# Generate several smooth curves passing through a given set of points

Tags: python, interpolation, curve-fitting, spline, piecewise

I am trying to generate approximately 5000 distinct curves that pass through a predetermined set of points, representing layer interfaces within the earth. It is essential that these curves do not exhibit significant oscillations or abrupt changes between nearby points, as the internal structure of the Earth does not undergo such drastic changes. All the curves must pass through the given set of points.

At present, my workflow involves randomly generating points between the provided data points and attempting to fit curves to them, resulting in various curves. However, I am interested in exploring more efficient approaches to achieve this. I am also seeking recommendations for interpolation methods that can produce smooth behavior between points and avoid oscillatory tendencies.

Appreciate any guidance!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = [7.81, 21.65, 186.29, 246.62, 402.74, 446.24, 572.99, 585.11, 613.57, 762.97]
y = [26.27, 26.41, 26.46, 27.36, 34.32, 34.50, 37.94, 39.05, 39.23, 39.88]

# y can only range between 25 and 40

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
xnew = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=50)
oned = interpolate.CubicSpline(x, y)
yfit = oned(xnew)
plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')
plt.plot(xnew, yfit)
plt.xlim(0, 800)
plt.ylim(20,45)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

Example of one such curve:
[image: Example of one such curve]

Comment: Bezier splines are the correct kind of interpolation for this and you probably want to do something similar to what is described here to get the controls: https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/

Comment: This may be interesting to you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70156640/2836621

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve reminded me of a textbook example of a noise-free Gaussian Process (GP) Regression. GP is an advance machine learning topic that could be very useful for your use case. Here is a [terrific interactive tool](https://distill.pub/2019/visual-exploration-gaussian-processes/) for understanding GPs.

As explained there

> They allow us to make predictions about our data by incorporating prior knowledge. Their most obvious area of application is fitting a function to the data. This is called regression and is used, for example, in robotics or time series forecasting. But Gaussian processes are not limited to regression — they can also be extended to classification and clustering tasks. For a given set of training points, there are potentially infinitely many functions that fit the data. Gaussian processes offer an elegant solution to this problem by assigning a probability to each of these functions. The mean of this probability distribution then represents the most probable characterization of the data. Furthermore, using a probabilistic approach allows us to incorporate the confidence of the prediction into the regression result.

Let's see how you can use GP regression to accomplish what you want using the [`scikit-learn` library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html).

The code below is made of three functions:

- `train_gaussian_process`: your observations `x` and `y` are used to train the GP.
- `generate_samples_from_gp`: from the GP we've just trained, we sample 5 functions (in your case it will be 5000). The function values are stored in a 2D numpy array, where the *i*-th column represents the *i*-th function.
- `draw_samples`: draw the observations and the sampled functions.

A critical component of a GP is the covariance function. You asked for smooth functions and you want to avoid oscillatory behavior, so the [RBF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#radial-basis-function-rbf-kernel) kernel of the [Matern](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#matern-kernel) one could be the right choice. The code below uses the Matern kernel. Play around with their parameters to get what you want.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)


def main() -> None:
    x = [7.81, 21.65, 186.29, 246.62, 402.74, 446.24, 572.99, 585.11, 613.57, 762.97]
    y = [26.27, 26.41, 26.46, 27.36, 34.32, 34.50, 37.94, 39.05, 39.23, 39.88]

    x = np.array(x).reshape((-1, 1))
    y = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)

    z = data_generating_process(x, y)

    sample_size = 5  # replace with 5_000

    gp_regressor = train_gaussian_process(x, y)
    gp_regressor_3d = train_gaussian_process(np.column_stack((x, y)), z)

    offset = 5.0
    additional_x = np.linspace(min(x) - offset, max(x) + offset, 1000).reshape((-1, 1))

    x_ = np.linspace(min(x) - offset, max(x) + offset, 50)
    y_ = np.linspace(min(y) - offset, max(y) + offset, 50)
    additional_xy = np.array([[_x, _y] for _x in x_ for _y in y_]).squeeze(-1)

    samples = generate_samples_from_gp(gp_regressor, additional_x, sample_size)
    samples_3d = generate_samples_from_gp(gp_regressor_3d, additional_xy, sample_size)

    draw_samples(x, y, samples, additional_x)
    draw_samples_3d(x, y, z, samples_3d, additional_xy)


def data_generating_process(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Generate points from a test function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : np.ndarray
    y : np.ndarray

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray

    """
    return y + np.log(x)


def train_gaussian_process(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> GaussianProcessRegressor:
    """
    Train Gaussian Process.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : np.ndarray
    y : np.ndarray

    Returns
    -------
    GaussianProcessRegressor

    """
    kernel = Matern(length_scale=4.0, nu=2.5)
    gaussian_process = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)
    gaussian_process.fit(x, y)
    return gaussian_process


def generate_samples_from_gp(
    gaussian_process: GaussianProcessRegressor, points: np.ndarray, sample_size: int
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Sample functions from Gaussian Process.

    Parameters
    ----------
    gaussian_process : np.ndarray
    points : np.ndarray
    sample_size : int

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray

    """
    return gaussian_process.sample_y(points, n_samples=sample_size)


def draw_samples(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, samples: np.ndarray, points: np.ndarray
) -> None:
    """
    Draw samples.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : np.ndarray
    y : np.ndarray
    samples : np.ndarray
    points : np.ndarray

    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 3))
    plt.scatter(x, y, label="Observations")
    for i in range(samples.shape[1]):
        plt.plot(points, samples[:, i], linewidth=1.2)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def draw_samples_3d(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, z: np.ndarray, samples: np.ndarray, points: np.ndarray
) -> None:
    """
    Draw samples.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : np.ndarray
    y : np.ndarray
    z : np.ndarray
    samples : np.ndarray
    points : np.ndarray

    """

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 4))

    n = int(np.sqrt(points.shape[0]))
    x_grid = points[:, 0].reshape((n, n))
    y_grid = points[:, 1].reshape((n, n))

    for i in range(samples.shape[1]):
        axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 5, i + 1, projection="3d")

        axis.scatter(x, y, z, label="Observations", s=100, alpha=1)
        z_grid = samples[:, i].reshape((n, n))
        axis.plot_surface(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid, cmap=plt.cm.plasma)
        axis.set_xlabel("x-axis")
        axis.set_ylabel("y-axis")
        axis.set_zlabel("z-axis")
        axis.set_title(f"Sample {i + 1}")

    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see from the image below, all the functions will pass through your observations.
[image]

You can also get the mean function by typing:

```py
mean_prediction = gp_regressor.predict(additional_x)
```

Here is the resulting plot with 5000 functions!

[image]

The code above is general so it's ready to be used for a *n*-dimensional use case. For instance, below 5 sample for a 3D case (I have suppose that the data generating process is `x + ln(y)`, but you can choose whatever you want, I needed this equation to get the `z` values for the training step).

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the answer. I have a couple follow up questions. How do I get the probabilities associated with each of these functions? Eventually I want to expand this idea to a 3D surfaces (Given a set of points on a 2D plane, generate ~5000 3D surfaces passing through the points). I could not find many examples online for higher dimensions. How should I approach it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome! The code is ready to be used for a *n*-dimensional use case. You just to perform some simple pre-processing your data. I have edited my answer, and I have added a function for plotting surfaces in 3D space.

Comment: Hi, I was able to generate several curves thanks to the above code. But I want to constrain all the posterior sampled curves to lie between two values (25 to 40). Is there a way to do it by modifying the kernel. I've tried Matern and RBF at various length scale and smoothing factor values. But I was not able to constrain the curves. https://pasteboard.co/AoE0fWgbFYk0.png. Appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Hi! I'm glad that my example was useful! As far as I know, it is not directly possible to impose such a constrain. For sure by modifying the kernel you can get what you want but it won't be so easy for such a particular constraint. A very dirty, not efficient, but simple solution that comes to my mind is to sample the curves from the GP iteratively, i.e. sample just one curve and check if it lies in the custom y-range, if it does keep the curve, otherwise discard it and repeat the sampling until you get 5000 curves that satisfy the y-range constrain.